# spherical mesh using pdepe

Tags: matlab, mesh, pde, spherical-coordinate

I was wondering if it possible to have a spherical mesh using the **pdepe** function of Matlab? My system of pdes are defined in a sphere, so I want to solve accordingly. My internet search didn't give helpful results, unfortunately. Thank you in advance!

Comment: [The docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop) say this is a 1d solver. How would that work for a sphere?

Comment: I have missed that..